# javascript function using jquery addClass() method does not add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

The script works, creates everything correctly, etc., but the jquery addClass method isn't adding the class. I'm new to using jquery methods in a javascript function, any help is appreciated, including alternate methods for adding the appropriate classes without using jquery.

```
function thumbnail(Img, Element, Modal, ModalTitle) {
"use strict";
/*jslint browser:true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/
//this function will append an anchor tag with the appropriate functionality, accepting inputs on the image filename, attaching element, and modal
//Img = full filename in format of foo.png
//Element = the ID of the element within which the thumbnail anchor will be placed
//Modal = the ID of the modal
//ModalTitle = Text used for title of the modal and title of the caption
var image, element, modal, loc, output, iUrl, modal_loc, modal_output, mtitle;
image = Img;
element = Element;
modal = Modal;
mtitle = ModalTitle;
iUrl = "/design-library/images/thumbs/" + image;
output = "<a href='#' data-reveal-id='" + modal + "'>";
output += "<img class='sample_img' src='" + iUrl + "' alt='" + mtitle + "' />";
output += "</a>";
output += "<p class='caption'>" + mtitle + "</p>";
modal_output = "<h1>" + mtitle + "</h1>";
modal_output += "<img src='" + iUrl + "' alt='" + image + "' /><a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>";
//create the modal container
$(modal).addClass('reveal-modal');
modal_loc = document.getElementById(modal);
modal_loc.innerHTML = modal_output;
//the end of the script gets the element and adds the anchor tag that exists in output
$(element).addClass('samples');
loc = document.getElementById(element);
loc.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: Please regards, how could you call thumbnail function? the parameters that you supply it.

Comment: SEMSEM, like this: 'thumbnail('page_schedule.png','thumb1','modal_2','Schedule Page');'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `modal` and `element` are IDs, you should correct your selectors to use them as ones:

```
$('#' + modal).addClass('reveal-modal');
$('#' + element).addClass('samples');
```

Side note. Once you have found the DOM element with jQuery, there is no need to perform the second search with `getElementById`:

```
var modal_loc = $('#' + modal);
modal_loc.addClass('reveal-modal');
modal_loc.html(modal_output);
```

Comment: So, thanks for the additional help! This was exactly it, and I award it the answer over the others because of the additional mods. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

if `modal` is an ID string, you need to do:

```
$('#'+modal).addClass('reveal-modal');
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed how to use a string in the jquery call.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$(element).addClass('samples');
```

to

```
$('#' + element).addClass('samples');
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the clue-in on using a variable for the jquery.

Comment: no problem. The hardest part for me when starting to use jQuery was learning the selectors. This is a bit of a curve and it can be daunting.